# System.Overflow Exception - int32 is too large or small

Tags: c#, overflow

I need a little advice.

I've got windows service that runs at night. In my development environment, it runs without exception, but when I running it "installed on other machines", when I come in the morning, I'm welcomed with a System.Overflow exception that says that I've set an int32 to a value that is too large or small.

I've carefully combed the service's c# code, and I have try/catch statements around everything, that should catch any error and write it to a log without completely stopping my service with this overflow exception. But still, it occurs and stops the service.

I'd appreciate any conceptual advice on how to pin point what's causing an error such as this.

Comment: What is the exception's stack trace?

Comment: attach a remote debugger to it

Comment: Or if the overflow don't matter change the assignment where the error occurs to: myint = unchecked(assignment); This will let the overflow roll over. But you might want to track down the error first.

Comment: The machines on which the exception is occurring, don't have visual studio 2010 on them, so I haven't figured out a way to get a stack trace yet. As I mentioned, I've tried to get that by putting try/catch statements around everything, and writing catches to a log, but it hasn't turned up anything yet.

Comment: If you put a debug build on the machine you can generate a stacktrace with out VS take a look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx

Comment: Doesn't the exception's stack trace tell you where it is in the code? Figure it out from there.

Comment: Or a release build, but include the pdb files for including line numbers in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You must have missed an instance of try/catch or you have an error in your error handler or it would be handled.
- In windows you can setup your service to restart if it ends unexpected manner.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with adding `try/catch` blocks throughout your code is it's easy to miss a place and hence not log the exception.  A much more robust approach is to use the value `AppDomain.UnhandledException`.  This will fire for any exception which is not handled within the current `AppDomain`.  You can hook into this to write to your log file and hopefully get a better idea at where the error is coming form

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;

...

void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
 // Log the exception here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let me tell you that overflow/underflow can be disabled, by opening project properties, selecting "Build" (from the left menu), and then "Advanced...".

By the way, I do it all the time, because it adds overhead, which I don't want in my scientific applications. Manually, then I control things.

But that does not solve the issues... It just hides the "problem", if it is a problem.

If you only care to check about a zero/non zero condition, somewhere in your code, disabling overflow at project settings solves the problem, because even when an overflow occurs you get a nonzero value, and your service continues without problems.

Comment: Do you disable this by default, or only in your release builds? I hope the latter so that you remove any potential errors in your code, or that you have unit tests to cover this :) And it's better to disable it where you know it's ok with the unchecked keyword imo.

Comment: @Mikael Svenson: You are right, in release build I disable arithmetic overflows/underflows, due to the involved overhead.

Comment: Never knew that was there, but it seems to be disabled by default. Turning it on doesn't seem to make a discernible performance difference in my raytracer, perhaps the JIT just doesn't think it's necessary.

Comment: @JulianR: for GUI code or code that does not perform intensive calculations (like mathematical computations) you will not notice any difference. But, try to play with this option on code that solves a system of 200000 simultaneous equations, and you'll see!

Comment: I'd put a realtime raytracer in the "computationally intensive" category. Still doesn't make any difference. Not saying the checks don't have a performance impact, just saying that those checks *don't seem to be actually there at all*.

Answer (score 1):

Also, for WinForms applications:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx

And WPF:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx

To get visibility of exceptions on UI threads, since they're not forwarded to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException.